# Creating custom objects group of rounded rectangles in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been searching for a while now. I want to recreate this: https://fwa.thecoolclub.co/

More specifically said I want to recreate the laying deck of cards. I know that they've made it with Three.JS and my only goal is to place the cards exactly like that link.

Right now I'm facing the difficulty that I have no experience with JavaScript or 3D-rendered objects. However I choose this project for my study and I want to succeed. Can someone **please** help me with this?

My code right now doesn't even make sense and should be in the trash. Therefore I did not include it. Sorry for the question, but this is my last hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes) to create the rounded rectangle look of the cards via [`THREE.Shape`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/extras/core/Shape).

This is how you would make a flat card. ([live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-three-zf57t))

```js
// Configure card shape
const x = 0;
const y = -0.1;
const width = 1;
const height = 1.2;
const radius = 0.2;

// Create card shape
const shape = new THREE.Shape()
  .moveTo(x, y + radius)
  .lineTo(x, y + height - radius)
  .quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x + radius, y + height)
  .lineTo(x + width - radius, y + height)
  .quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius)
  .lineTo(x + width, y + radius)
  .quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width - radius, y)
  .lineTo(x + radius, y)
  .quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y + radius);

// Create card mesh
const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The grid is just calculating and displacing cards based on their size and desired distance. You can get the dimensions/size of an object with [`Box3#getSize`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.getSize). I use this in the above demo to center the object in the scene.

```js
const size = new THREE.Vector3();
new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh).getSize(size);
```